# DBGeography latitude and longitude properties throw NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-6

I have some problems using `DbGeography` entities through WCF Service.
When I try to read the properties `Longitude` and `Latitude` (actually all properties except `WellKnownValue`) on the client side I get nothing but a `NotImplementedException`.

I can use them on server side without any problem.

The providers are different between client and server.

Client: `System.Data.Entity.Spatial.DefaultSpatialServices`

Service: `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlSpatialServices`

The problem seems to come from here but I can't figure out how to change it.
The client and server are both running on the same machine.

Does anyone knows how to deal with this problem ?

Here is the complete error:

```
No usable spatial provider could be found. In order to use the 'DbGeography' or 'DbGeometry' spatial types the EF provider being used must support spatial types and all prerequisites for the provider must be installed.
```

Thank you.